# Using autoreconf without root rights on a prefix path results in a corrupted configure-script

Tags: ubuntu, compiling, autoreconf

I am trying to compile a package (libdrm-2.4.59) and to use `sed` and `autoreconf` to remove a dependency:

```
sed -e "/pthread-stubs/d" -i configure.ac &&
autoreconf -fiv
```

It produces the following output:

```
autoreconf: Entering directory `.'
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gettext
autoreconf: running: aclocal -I /u/f0/students/estermad/tmp/share/aclocal --force -I m4 ${ACLOCAL_FLAGS}
autoreconf: configure.ac: tracing
autoreconf: running: libtoolize --install --copy --force
libtoolize: putting auxiliary files in AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR, 'build-aux'.
libtoolize: copying file 'build-aux/config.guess'
libtoolize: copying file 'build-aux/config.sub'
libtoolize: copying file 'build-aux/install-sh'
libtoolize: copying file 'build-aux/ltmain.sh'
libtoolize: putting macros in AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIRS, 'm4'.
libtoolize: copying file 'm4/libtool.m4'
libtoolize: You should add the contents of 'm4/libtool.m4' to 'aclocal.m4'.
libtoolize: copying file 'm4/ltoptions.m4'
libtoolize: You should add the contents of 'm4/ltoptions.m4' to 'aclocal.m4'.
libtoolize: copying file 'm4/ltsugar.m4'
libtoolize: You should add the contents of 'm4/ltsugar.m4' to 'aclocal.m4'.
libtoolize: copying file 'm4/ltversion.m4'
libtoolize: copying file 'm4/lt~obsolete.m4'
libtoolize: You should add the contents of 'm4/lt~obsolete.m4' to 'aclocal.m4'.
autoreconf: running: /usr/bin/autoconf --force
autoreconf: running: /usr/bin/autoheader --force
autoreconf: running: automake --add-missing --copy --force-missing
configure.ac:32: installing `build-aux/missing'
exynos/Makefile.am: installing `build-aux/depcomp'
autoreconf: Leaving directory `.'
```

This looks fine so far but as I call `configure` the build stops with a strange error:

```
...
checking for pkg-config... /u/f0/students/estermad/tmp/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for PCIACCESS... configure: error: in `/u/f0/students/estermad/xc/libdrm-2.4.59':
configure: error: The pkg-config script could not be found or is too old.  Make sure it
is in your PATH or set the PKG_CONFIG environment variable to the full
path to pkg-config.
...
```

Here are some parts of the `config.log` which show the error, the corresponding compiler and linker flags which were set correctly and the values related to `pkg-config` which are not set:

```
configure:12927: checking for PCIACCESS
configure:12932: $PKG_CONFIG --exists --print-errors "pciaccess >= 0.10"
configure:12935: $? = 0
configure:12945: $PKG_CONFIG --exists --print-errors "pciaccess >= 0.10"
configure:12948: $? = 0
configure:12970: error: in `/u/f0/students/estermad/xc/libdrm-2.4.59':
...
ac_cv_env_PCIACCESS_CFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_PCIACCESS_CFLAGS_value=-I/u/f0/students/estermad/tmp/include
ac_cv_env_PCIACCESS_LIBS_set=set
ac_cv_env_PCIACCESS_LIBS_value='-L/u/f0/students/estermad/tmp/lib -lpciaccess'
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_set=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_value=
```

The `autoreconf` uses `libtoolize` which was missing on my system so I had to build `libtool` myself. All builds I do on this system have a prefix. The prefix used to build dependencies of `libdrm` among other things. For `libtool` I ran following:

```
$ cd libtool-2.4.5
$ ./configure --prefix=/u/f0/students/estermad/tmp && make && make install
$ libtool --finish /u/f0/students/estermad/tmp/lib
```

However the build and install of the libtool runs without any errors. I have no idea if the resulting `configure`-script is corrupted due to `autoreconf` (located in /usr/bin/autoreconf), `libtoolize` (located in /u/f0/students/estermad/tmp/bin), `aclocal` or something different.

I tried to build `libdrm` without using `autoreconf`, commenting out `pthread-stubs` manually. The build ran fine. Hence the above stated issue reveals only after running `autoreconf`. I would really appreciate some useful hints.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to update pkg-config to the latest version (0.28 at the moment). I had 0.18.